# Probability of drawing N elements from M elements with per element draw probability without replacement

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, numpy, probabilistic-programming

I have a list of M elements with per element draw probability, summing to 1.0.
Example (M=10): `L = [0.3, 0.2, 0.01, 0.05, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1]`
Now I randomly draw N elements without replacement, according to the elements probability. The command I use for that is  `np.random.choice(L, N, replace=False)`
Say now I got 3 elements with probabilities `{0.2, 0.05, 0.1}`.
How would I go about calculating the probability I had of drawing those 3 elements at the same time, irrespective of order?

edit: I think this is the relevant part of the numpy implementation of the choice function (p = L):

```
n_uniq = 0
p = p.copy()
found = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.int64)
flat_found = found.ravel()
while n_uniq < size:
     x = self.random((size - n_uniq,))
     if n_uniq > 0:
          p[flat_found[0:n_uniq]] = 0
     cdf = np.cumsum(p)
     cdf /= cdf[-1]
     new = cdf.searchsorted(x, side='right')
     _, unique_indices = np.unique(new, return_index=True)
     unique_indices.sort()
     new = new.take(unique_indices)
     flat_found[n_uniq:n_uniq + new.size] = new
     n_uniq += new.size
idx = found
[...]
return a.take(np.asarray(idx, dtype=np.intp), axis=axis)
```

Comment: Could you please provide details of how these "per draw" probabilities work when sampling *without* replacement?  For instance, suppose the first element is drawn at the first step.  What are the probabilities you intend to use for drawing at the second step?  There's more than one way to do this!

Comment: @whuber I'm using the numpy command [link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). I editet my post to include what I think is the relevant part of the source code. If that's not enough I can try searching for an explanation again later.

Comment: It looks like it simply renormalizes all remaining probabilities.  Unfortunately, that means any answer will be just as complicated as the process itself: in general, the probability of a set of size $k$ will be a sum of $k!$ terms, one for each possible ordering of the terms.